# Cannot add all values in dictionary (tried other methods, didn't work)

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I searched here thoroughly for codes to sum up all the values in my dictionary, but they didn't really work out.

```
hostel = {
    "Berlin": [18.0, 18.0],
    "Hamburg": [17.65, 17.65],
    "Cochem": [30],
    "Munich": [18.0, 18.0],
    "Salzburg": [18.0, 18.0],
    "Vienna": [19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0],
    "Budapest": [18.0, 18.0]
}
```

I tried sum(hostel.values()) and sum(d.itervalues()),  but the following message showed up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 16, in 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

My python version is before 3. I can easily write

```
sum(hostel["Berlin"]) + sum(hostel["Hamburg"]) + .....
```

to add up everything, but that looks pretty stupid.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
>>> sum(sum(x) for x in hostel.itervalues())
285.3
```

`(sum(x) for x in hostel.itervalues())` returns a generator expression containing the sum of all lists:

```
>>> gen = (sum(x) for x in hostel.itervalues())
>>> gen
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xa51e644>
```

Contents of this `genexp`:

```
>>> list(gen)
[36.0, 36.0, 35.3, 36.0, 36.0, 30, 76.0]
```

Now we pass that genexp to sum and it'll sum up all these numbers:

```
#due to list call above the generator got consumed, so we've to create a new generator again
>>> gen = (sum(x) for x in hostel.itervalues())
>>> sum(gen)
285.3
```

Comment: Oh, that's so neat! Thank you! Do you mind explaining a bit of the mechanism, i.e. where does the x go into the itervalues function and why is two sum() function necessarily?

Comment: Itervalues returns the values in the dict one by one as the argument `x`. Since `x` is a list, we must compute the sum of that list. `(sum(x) for x in hostel.itervalues())` will return a generator that has the sum of the values for each city: (36.0, 35.3, 30...) which must be summed again to compute the grand total.

Comment: @KrystalTse I've added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sum(chain.from_iterable(hostel.itervalues()))
285.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`sum([sum(x) for x in hostel.values()])`

Comment: Ashwini and I answered that at exactly the same second .. lol. List comprehension in python is awesome!

Comment: I used generator expression. :P

Comment: I was about to ask if that's what it was. I like it. But agreed, comprehensions in general are awesome.

Comment: Thank you for answering though! I have not heard of generator expression before, so I am looking into it now.

Comment: No sweat! Either answer will work, but Ashwini was more 'correct' than I, especially for larger sets of data.